# Rails 4 Devise Strong Parameters Admin Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, admin, strong-parameters

I have made a user and admin model using devise. I have used strong parameters in the **app/controllers/application_controller.rb** file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :password, :remember_me) }
  end

end
```

How do I whitelist the admin model?

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |a| a.permit(:login, :password, :remember_me) }
```

Also how do I whitelist the admin sign_up so that no variables may be passed into it? My guess is

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |a| a.permit()}
```

## UPDATE

I would like to edit my question.

My question is how do I get the admin model to automatically blacklist my admin sign up page? If I simply leave nothing then I can still sign up through the **"admins/sign_up"**. Sure I can delete the :regisitrations within the **"app/models/admin.rb"**, but I would like to deny command line sign ups

--Would it be wise to use scoped views and specifically define each view for the admin and user models?--

Comment: I think you should use a condition to check the controller inside your method conf_permitted_parameters and then permit admin and user accordingly

Comment: Can you provide me an example? I'm not really sure how that's done. Here is an idea I came across. Do not include registerable within the app/models/admin.rb file. That way you can only sign someone up through the command line. The problem is I still need to whitelist it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate controllers for users and admins then try something like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  if params[:controller] == "user"
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :password, :remember_me) }
  else
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |a| a.permit(:login, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |a| a.permit()}
```

and there's another approach to it as well, create only one controller for both users and admin, named registrations_controller.rb, have a field in your users table named is_admin and set it for a user only if he/she is a admin. Create a seed to make your admins like this in your seeds.rb file:

```
admin_user = User.new(email: "abc@xyz.com", password: "123", password_confirmation: "123", is_admin: "true" )
admin_user.skip_confirmation!
admin_user.save
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I used option 1 because option 2 is less secure and I want to avoid having an admin attribute in the users table.

Comment: I didn't realize it until now but configuring the controller like this ^^ does not allow me to signup. It allows me to sign in for both the admin and the user. However It does not allow the user to sign up. I think it has a problem when I leave these lines in. 


devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |a| a.permit(:login, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |a| a.permit()}