# Rails 4 Strong Parameters Devise User Admin Models

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, admin, strong-parameters

What is the best way to use Strong Parameters with Rails 4 and Devise for an Admin Model and User Model?

I want to allow the user to sign_in & sign_up ---  and the admin to sign_in however not sign_up.

Note* I have already read [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) by devise.

Answer (score 1):

It does not depend on strong_parameters. Remove `:registerable` from your admin model.

Comment: okay, how can I block unwanted parameters from being entered into the database manually then?

Comment: What's not working with this solution: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters ?

Comment: Here are some related questions about the same issue- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137244/rails-4-devise-strong-parameters-admin-model
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510289/rails-4-strong-parameters-opposite-permit-all-attributes
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/pAYxKP5h5Vg

Comment: If there is no attributes allowed why would you want to have this action and forms available in the first place? Why not just override it with a simple redirect or something?

Comment: I want to block the admin sign_up completely. And I thought the point of strong parameters is to make the site secure by not allowing anything other than what you permit to pass. If this is the case than I should not be allowed to pass attributes manually when I have blocked the admin sign_up